How to pronounce "en caul" correctly
I previously posted in Linguistics, but was directed here as a better place for this question. Here is the original content from my linguistics post.

My wife works in childbirth, and she learned to pronounce "en caul" as something liike "on coal". If I understand correctly, this originally a French or UK term meaning "born in an intact amniotic sack".
However, recently, she has been corrected several times that it's pronounced more like "en call". She usually just smiles and nods and continues pronouncing it the way she learned it, but she definitely went on a rant about it recently.
My take on it is that either both are correct pronunciations (due to language adoption), or the correct pronunciation falls somewhere in between. That said, I'm not a linguist by trade (hence why I probably used the incorrect language pronunciation characters), so I'm curious if anyone else has more context on this pronunciation disagreement.

However, someone pointed out the following:

It's a pseudo-French expression. There is no French word caul, it's actually just the English word.

Another individuals comments was

My guess would be that the en makes it look like a French expression, so some people pronounce it as such (even though caul is fully English). But collocations with en are in the process of losing their Frenchness, and pronunciations with /εn/ instead of /ɑ̃(n)/ are increasingly common; compare en route (which is French), traditionally /ɑ̃(n) ˈruːt/, now often /εn ˈruːt/ or /εn ˈraʊt/. But this a question about English, not linguistics – it would be a better fit on English Language & Usage than here.

So I guess my question, more succinctly is "In the US, what is the best way to pronounce 'en caul' when referring to an 'en caul birth'? Is there one right way, or are there any obviously wrong pronounciations?".

If she learned from other people in the childbirth field, I'd expect they know the accepted pronunciation. I don't think it's a common word outside the field (I've never heard it before now).

Hello, and welcome to ELU! If you could include a dictionary showing a pronunciation, or even better two with differing pronunciation, it would be a fine thing to do. Was one of the wife's teachers British by any chance? My British Aunt would say kol for "call", and most Americans say kahl, which sounds like the same difference that you describe.

"Cal"/"caul"/"caule" meaning amniotic membrane is cited as far back as 1547. Funk's 1896 dictionary defines "encowl" or "encaul" as meaning "to place a cowl on" (similar prefix to "enmesh" etc). I'm guessing this is the source, but no idea how it became Frenchified, other than by mistake. The earliest Google Books citation in the modern sense and two-word spelling is Physiology of Prematurity from 1959 or 1960. You'll find "caul" in a dictionary: the OED has UK /kɔːl/, US /kɔl/ or /kɑl/. None of which conclusively explains the pronunciation of "en caul".

I recommend finding some obstetrics videos and listening to them; I don't think you'll get a good answer from general English language references.

@Conrado I have tried looking up dictionary pronunciations without success. I suspect it's because each word maybe hash it's own definition, but I'm not sure. But the difference in British accent makes sense and I'll have to check with her.
